# RequireJS with server generated JS file

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs

I'm using RequireJS with a server generated file that contains translation strintgs and is reachable at `http://hostname/i18n.js`. I have added it to RequireJS with the `paths` config like so:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'i18n': '/i18n'
    },
});
```

Now I'm trying to minify this with `grunt-contrib-requirejs'` like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  'use strict';

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'), // the package file to use
    jsDir:        '<%= baseDir %>/static/js',

    requirejs: {
      compile: {
        options: {
          mainConfigFile: "<%= jsDir %>/common.js",
          dir: '/tmp/www-release',
          modules : [
            {
              name: 'common',
              exclude: ['i18n'],
              include: [
                /* some filess */
              ]

            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');


};
```

As you can see, I have excluded `i18n`. Yet I still get the following error when running `grunt requirejs`:

```
Running "requirejs:compile" (requirejs) task
[Error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/i18n.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
]
```

How do I tell grunt to ignore the translation strings?

Comment: Is something in 'common' referencing i18n?

Comment: No, common only contains the requirejs.config. But some files in `include` to reference it

Comment: Is it referenced from within the include files with require, or define?

Comment: i18n is reference with both `require` and `define` in different files.